# Recoding with Case Statement with 2 Count functions where both are required to be true

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a new column "PolicyStatus" with a case statement.  The the value of the case statement is dependent upon counting the number of occurrences of two variables and both of those variables have to occur a specific number of times.

Here is an example:

Grouping by OpportuntiyID, a policy is "Within Policy" if there are at least 3 QuoteID AND There are at least 3 Within7 that have a value of "Yes".  Below is a sample data and my code thus far.  Something is not going right with my case statement but I am not sure how to correct it.

The error that I am getting is:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 35
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

This is referring to the case statement directly.

I thank you all in advanced for your assistance in correcting this.

> OpportunityID,QUOTEID,DaysPassed,Within7
>   0060c00001QF5jiAAD,a060c00001REnnuAAD,-81,No
>   0060c00001QF5jiAAD,a060c00001REnpqAAD,-81,No
>   0060c00001QF5jiAAD,a060c00001REnsBAAT,-81,No
>   0060c00001QGz6JAAT,NULL,NULL,No
>   0060c00001QHxZhAAL,a060c00001cVlyzAAC,-32,No
>   0060c00001QHxZhAAL,a060c00001cVlzEAAS,-32,No
>   0060c00001QHxZhAAL,a060c00001cVm02AAC,-32,No
>   0060c00001QHxZhAAL,a060c00001cVm0bAAC,-32,No
>   0060c00001QHxZhAAL,a060c00001cUhzeAAC,0,Yes
>   0060c00001QIaK3AAL,a060c00001cV9YeAAK,4,Yes
>   0060c00001QIaK3AAL,a060c00001cV9YZAA0,4,Yes
>   0060c00001QIFfZAAX,a060c00001REtIEAA1,43,Yes
>   0060c00001QIk2UAAT,a060c00001cUYm9AAG,18,Yes
>   0060c00001QIk2UAAT,a060c00001cUYmEAAW,18,Yes
>   0060c00001QIk2UAAT,a060c00001cUYmTAAW,18,Yes
>   0060c00001QIwgaAAD,a060c00001cVMekAAG,0,Yes
>   0060c00001QIWoPAAX,a060c00001cW8eAAAS,-35,No
>   0060c00001QIYKbAAP,a060c00001cUYHkAAO,-65,No
>   0060c00001QIYKbAAP,a060c00001cUYKtAAO,-65,No
>   0060c00001QIYKbAAP,a060c00001RDzNYAA1,6,Yes
>   0060c00001QL7bkAAD,a060c00001cUQCmAAO,21,Yes
>   0060c00001QL7bkAAD,a060c00001cUQCXAA4,21,Yes
>   0060c00001QL7bkAAD,a060c00001cUQDkAAO,21,Yes
>   0060c00001QLWg6AAH,NULL,NULL,No
>   0060c00001QxJSgAAN,NULL,NULL,No
>   0060c00001QxOe4AAF,NULL,NULL,No
>   0060c00001Rae5dAAB,a060c00001cUvOLAA0,3,Yes
>   0060c00001Rb5RoAAJ,a060c00001cUWgEAAW,8,Yes
>   0060c00001Rb5RoAAJ,a060c00001cUWgJAAW,8,Yes
>   0060c00001Rb8wuAAB,a060c00001cUvEaAAK,-1,Yes
>   0060c00001Rb8wuAAB,a060c00001cUvEGAA0,-1,Yes

```
SELECT
    [OPPORTUNITYID]
  , COUNT([QUOTEID]) AS 'CountOfQuotes'
  , CASE WHEN COUNT([QUOTEID]) >= 3 AND COUNT([WITHIN7] = 'YES') >=3 THEN 'Within Policy'
         ELSE 'Breached Policy' END AS 'PolicyStatus'
FROM [DB].dbo.[TABLE]
GROUP BY [OPPORTUNITYID]
ORDER BY [OpportunityID]
GO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do conditional aggregation on the `WITHIN7` column, counting how many times 'YES' appears.  One option is to count a `CASE` expression.

```
SELECT
    [OPPORTUNITYID],
    COUNT([QUOTEID]) AS [CountOfQuotes],
    CASE WHEN COUNT([QUOTEID]) >= 3 AND
        COUNT(CASE WHEN [WITHIN7] = 'YES' THEN 1 END) >= 3
         THEN 'Within Policy'
         ELSE 'Breached Policy' END AS [PolicyStatus]
FROM [DB].dbo.[TABLE]
GROUP BY [OPPORTUNITYID]
ORDER BY [OpportunityID];
```

Comment: This actually works. The only adjustment that I had to make was to turn the COUNT(CASE...) statement into a SUM.  Looks like this:

CASE WHEN COUNT([QUOTEID]) >= 3 AND
        SUM(CASE WHEN [WITHIN7] = 'YES' THEN 1 END) >= 3
         THEN 'Within Policy'
         ELSE 'Breached Policy' END AS [PolicyStatus]

Comment: @Chris The `COUNT` of a `CASE` which I wrote should work exactly the same as the sum you wrote.

Comment: Oh shoot your right. It’s not a Count(Distinct...) so it would have counter how many times something existed.

Comment: Yeah...I usually choose it, because it is slightly more compact than `sum`, which needs an explicit `else` condition of zero.  But, you may use whichever you prefer.

Comment: Oh I didn’t know that. Good to know. Thanks